# Inference of root mean square value in terms of house prediction

Tags: predictive-modeling, prediction, model-selection

The objective of the task is to predict the housing prices. A model is created based on California housing dataset to predict housing prices and is subjected to evaluation using the below code.

```
    from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

    housing_predictions = lin_reg.predict(housing_prepared)
    error = mean_squared_error(housing_labels,housing_predictions)
    rmse = np.sqrt(error) --> prediction error

    // value I got for rmse was - 68628.1981
```

The average housing prices range from 120,000 - 265,000. But the rmse value is 
68628.1981.

> Questions

1. By looking at rmse value, What should I infer?. I know the model is underfitting. I wanted to know the intuition behind the rmse value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RMSE is a measure for how "wrong" a regression model's predictions are on average, and is mostly useful as a relative metric for determining which of a set of models is best. If you want an absolute baseline against which to compare any given model you can always compute the standard deviation of your target, which is the RMSE of a model which predicts the average value of $y$ for every observation.

I would also argue that for something like housing prices a more meaningful error measure is root mean square *logarithmic* error, which is the RMSE after taking the log of $y$ (or $y + 1$ if $y$ contains zeros) and the predicted values. The reason for this is that we're interested in errors as proportions of our target (an error of \$50,000 is much more serious for a \$100,000 house compared to a \$1,000,000 house), and taking logs is the way to adjust for this. Also be sure to focus on test or cross validation error, else you will always choose your most overfit model.